# How to add one year in __time32_t

Tags: c++, datetime

Hi i'm not that good in C++ and I would like just to know how to add one year in this code:

```
__time32_t tempTime;    
_time32(&tempTime);
```

In this scenario it will give you the current date.
What I want is to add one year.

I am about to try this code:

```
__time32_t now, result; 
struct tm  when;
int year = 1;
_time32(&now);
_localtime32_s( &when, &now );
when.tm_year = when.tm_year + year;
result = mktime(&when);
trans.expiration = result;
```

Comment: You need to define your problem a bit better. By "one year", do you mean the same time on the same date the next year? What does that mean if it's a leap day? If there's a leap second, what happens?

Comment: my bad, what i mean is adding 365 days into it..

Comment: If the question is now incorrect, edit it - adding corrections in the (temporary) comments is not how SO works. Adding 365 days is trivial (and not the same as adding a year).  `__time32_t` is an arithmetic object representing seconds since the start of the epoch - just add 365 days worth of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a `tm` structure, increment the year member, convert back to `__time32_t`.

Comment: Unless, of course, you are starting on Feb 29th and land on a non-leap-year after the increment...

Comment: @MattJohnson : No, it will still work.  The conversion from `struct tm` to `time_t` using `mktime()` *normalises* the time.  For example if you change 29 Feb 2016 to 29 Feb 2017, `mktime()` will fix-up the `tm` to 1 Mar 2017 *and* output the correct epoch time value.  It works for any date - 32 Jan for example normalises to 1 Feb, so you can use the technique also for adding a number of days.

Comment: Nice!  So then, fundamentally, `mktime` is different than Window's `SystemTimeToFileTime` behavior, which does *not* normalize. Right?

Comment: Also, if one expected Feb 29 2016 + 1yr to be Feb 28 2017, then they'd have to account for that manually.

Comment: @MattJohnson : Yes, but the argument for mapping 29 Feb  + 1 year to 1 March is that it represents the same number of days from the start of the year, and also +365 days.  It is therefore arithmetically consistent.  If you were born of 29 February, you might celebrate on 28 February, but humans attach cultural significance to such things that are largely irrational - you have to code such those cultural norms explicitly - maths won't help.

Answer (score 0):

__time32_t is just a aliased long integer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4ddyt9h.aspx) isn't it?

So if you want to add 365 days to it, couldn't you just do something like this:

```
__time32_t now;
_time32(&now);
__time32_ result = now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
```

? Where 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 is number of seconds in one year (365 years).

Comment: NOTE: I'm basing my answer on "my bad, what i mean is adding 365 days into it.", this code won't handle leap years etc. But it should add 365 days, what's what you wnat.